# C: How's memory assigned when using pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals, playing-cards

I was just looking at this example from [Deitel](http://www.deitel.com/Books/C/CHowtoProgram6e/tabid/3527/Default.aspx):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct card aCard;
    struct card *cardPtr;
    aCard.face = "Aces";
    aCard.suit = "Spades";
    cardPtr = &aCard;

    printf( "%s%s%s\n%s%s%s\n%s%s%s\n", aCard.face, " of ", aCard.suit,
        cardPtr->face, " of ", cardPtr->suit,
        ( *cardPtr ).face, " of ", ( *cardPtr ).suit
    );

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I see there's a pointer to char but never thought you could save strings using `char *`...

The question is: how is memory handled here, because I didn't see any thing like `char word[50]`.

Comment: Please note that it's bad practice nowadays to assign a string literal to a variable of type `char*` like this.  You should instead use a variable of `const char*`, since string literal can not be (and should not be) modified at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler reserves some memory location large enough to store the literal and assigns its address to the pointer. Thereafter you can use it like a normal `char *`. One caveat is that you cannot modify the memory it points to.

```
char *str = "This is the end";
printf("%s\n", str);

str[5] = 0; /* Illegal. */
```

Incidentally, this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html) also discusses the matter.

Comment: @Jorge That's pretty much it, yeah.

Comment: `undefined` is more accurate than `Illegal`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it:

Excepción no controlada en 0x774315de en Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al escribir en la ubicación 0x003d574d.

I learnt something new lol.

Comment: @Jorge "once done it can't be modified?" -- Your wording suggests some confusion, as there is no "once done" here that cannot be redone. The *string* (the memory pointed to by the pointer) can't be modified; the pointer can be.

Answer (score 1):

The string constants `"Aces"`, `"Spades"`, *etc.*, are not just compile-time literals. The compiler allocates space for these in (usually read-only) program memory.

Answer (score 0):

aCard.face = "Aces";     aCard.suit = "Spades"; 
depending upon the compiler where it keeps string literals. If in Read only segment, changing it will result in segmentation fault, if in writable for example stack segment you can modify. So the behavior is undefined!!